# Change DIV height relatively

Tags: jquery, position, html

I'm using a [sticky footer](http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/cross-browser-sticky-footer-with-fluid-height-using-jquery.html) method for my `footer` `<div>`, to look better I want to resize the sidebar to fit between header and footer. Like this green line:
[image]

I'm using this line of code inside the `stickyFooter` function, but does not work:

```
$("#sidebar").height($(window).height() - $(footer).height() - 
$("#header").height());
```

What makes me to tell it does not work? It scrolls to infinity! You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/sxcmr/embedded/result/

And here, you can find the all stuffs: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/sxcmr/

The last thing, I don't want to use other methods of same height columns.

Comment: You have a JS error, check-out your console on that JSFiddle.

Comment: Fixed the bugs in your code http://jsfiddle.net/sxcmr/1/show/

Comment: Thanks @AamirAfridi, removing window.onresize() worked. Explain it in answers, i'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove window.onresize()
Made some changes to your code http://jsfiddle.net/sxcmr/1/show/

Instead of calling plugin on resize or load, just use

```
$("#footer").stickyFooter();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me (jQuery not required):

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

site body here ("push" must be empty)

<div class="push"></div>
</div><!-- wrapper end -->

<div class="footer_cont">
    <div class="footer">
        your footer here...
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html { height:100%; }
body { height:100%; }

.wrapper {
min-height:100%;
height:auto !important;
height:100%;    
margin:0 auto 64px; }

.push { height: 64px; }
.footer_cont { height:64px; }
.footer { margin:0px auto; width:960px; }
```

As you can see footer is 64px high and 960 wide.